# Display custom element in listview command bar

Tags: spfx, spfx-extensions

I'm a beginner SPFx developer so maybe my question is dumb, but here it goes.

I created a custom action for moving files to different site collection, but the problem is that the user doesn't know if it finished already or no.

Because of that I would like to display spinner or something like that in the command bar similarly to what SharePoint does when you move files.

[image]

Can anybody guide what I should do or what to read about to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please see: https://pnp.github.io/blog/post/how-to-use-loader-spinner-in-progress-indicator-in-spfx-using/
And: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71225672/fluent-ui-how-to-display-overlay-a-spinner-component-in-a-textfield-where-icon